# How to update boolean value in MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I'm currently writing a Next.js, and I'm not sure how to update the isBookmarked boolean value in my code that will persist to the database from my component. Here's what I have currently.

Item.js

```
<Item>
...
<div onClick={????????}>....</div> //Update value on database from here
...
</Item>
```

index.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
  const client = await clientPromise;

  const db = client.db("mediaData")
  let media = await db.collection("media").find({}).toArray();
  media = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(media));
  

  return{
    props:{ media} 
  }
}
......
media.map((item) => (
            <Item
              key={item._id}
              mediaBookmarked={item.isBookmarked} // value recived from the database
              year={item.year}
              category={item.category}
              rating={item.rating}
              title={item.title}
              small={item.thumbnail.trending.small}
              large={item.thumbnail.trending.large}
            />
....
```

Will I need to define a schema? I manually imported the information that populates this database from a JSON file.

Comment: You can use `collection.updateOne` or `updateMany` method to update any field in a MongoDB collection's document(s). See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Comment: so would the best place to call that be from inside the Item component? how would that function look?

Comment: Typically updates are triggered by users on some button click, for example. So, a button click starts the update process from the client (the code in your browser). The listener attached to the button component would call some some server side API, for example using the JavaScript `fetch`.

Comment: Yeah I understand that there would probably be a function passed in the onClick. Butwould that mean another getServerSideProps inside of the Item Component much like the one in index.js?

Comment: Yes, another function like `updateSomeThingInDatabase` would have the call to the server. I suspect you need to refer some simple examples online. For example, you can search for "how to make update call to nextjs backend from a react component".

Comment: Trust me Ive searched it without a real clear example.

Comment: If you are not finding any or right examples online - then you probably dont know what to look for _or_ you are trying a wrong project (or assignment or tutorial). In a fullstack app, you need to understand how the data flows from the front end components to the back end application and the database (and the data flow from database to the front end).